# Tkinter widgets set to appear in multiple windows appear in the same window

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have a few different widgets in my python program: `infobar` and `texteditor` are in my `App` class; `commandline` and `output` in my `Terminal` class. But when I run the program, the command line and output appear in my App window.

```
class Terminal(Frame):
### A window used for running Terminal commands.

def __init__(self, master):
    ### Initialize the Terminal app.
    # Initialize frame
    frame = Frame(terminalroot)
    frame.pack()

    # Create fonts
    txtFont = tkFont.Font(family="Monaco",size=10)

    # Initilize Commandline.
    self.commandline = Text(wrap=None,font=txtFont,width=40,height=1)
    self.commandline.pack()

    # Initialize Output.
    self.output = Text(wrap=WORD,font=txtFont,width=40,height=30)
    self.output.pack()

class App(Frame):
### The main application window.
    def __init__(self, master):
    ### Initialize the program.
    ## Initialize the frame
    ##  Setup the frame.
    ##  Set the title of the window.
    ##  Pack the frame.
    ## Initialize random class variables.
    ## Create fonts.
    ##  txtFont: Monaco, size 10. Used for most of the text areas.
    ## Create and pack the editor.
    ##  Wrap text along words.
    ##  Set size to W120 and H20.
    ##  Insert a short message to the text editor.
    ##  Reset any undo/redos.
    ##  Pack the editor.
    ## Setup tags.
    ##  Alert, sel.
    ## Create and pack the info bar.
    ##  Set size to W120 and H1.
    ##  Insert Info bar to the info bar.
    ## Setup the menu bar.
    ##  File:
    ##   Save, ^S, save_it
    ##   Save as, ^[shift]S, save_it_as
    ##   Load, ^L, load_it_and_clear
    ##   Import, ^I, load_it
    ##  Edit:
    ##   Undo, ^Z, undo
    ##   Redo, ^Y, redo
    ##  Style:
    ##   Default, no shortcut, set_theme_default
    ##   White on Black, no shortcut, set_theme_wob
    ##   Homebrew, no shortcut, set_theme_hbrew
    ## Setup the popup menu.
    ##  Undo, ^Z, undo
    ##  Redo, ^Y, redo
    ## Bind various commands.
    ## Final configuration.
    self.frame = Frame(root, background="black")
    root.title("BasicEdit")
    self.frame.pack()

    self.filename = "Hello World.txt"

    txtFont = tkFont.Font(family="Monaco", size=10)

    self.texteditor = Text(wrap=WORD,font=txtFont,width=120,height=20)
    self.texteditor.insert(END, """Lorem epsum...""")
    self.texteditor.edit_reset()
    self.texteditor.pack()

    self.texteditor.tag_config("alert", foreground="white", background="black")
    self.texteditor.tag_config("sel", foreground="blue")

    self.infobar = Text(font=txtFont,height=1,width=120)
    self.infobar.insert(END, "Info bar")
    self.infobar.pack()

    self.menubar = Menu()
    self.filemenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
    self.filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.save_it, accelerator="Ctrl+S")
    self.filemenu.add_command(label="Save as", command=self.save_it_as, accelerator="Ctrl+Shift+S")
    self.filemenu.add_command(label="Load", command=self.load_it_and_clear, accelerator="Ctrl+L")
    self.filemenu.add_command(label="Import", command=self.load_it, accelerator="Ctrl+I")
    self.editmenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
    self.editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=self.undo, accelerator="Ctrl+Z")
    self.editmenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=self.redo, accelerator="Ctrl+Y")
    self.stylemenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
    self.stylemenu.add_command(label="Default", command=self.set_theme_default)
    self.stylemenu.add_command(label="White on Black", command=self.set_theme_wob)
    self.stylemenu.add_command(label="Homebrew", command=self.set_theme_hbrew)
    self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
    self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=self.editmenu)
    self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Style", menu=self.stylemenu)

    self.popup = Menu(tearoff=1)
    self.popup.add_command(label="Undo", command=self.undo, accelerator="Ctrl+Z")
    self.popup.add_command(label="Redo", command=self.redo, accelerator="Ctrl+Y")
    root.bind("<Button-2>", self.rightmenu)

    root.bind("<Control-q>", self.quit)
    root.bind("<Control-Q>", self.quit)
    root.bind("<Control-s>", self.save_it)
    root.bind("<Control-S>", self.save_it)
    root.bind("<Control-l>", self.load_it_and_clear)
    root.bind("<Control-L>", self.load_it_and_clear)
    root.bind("<Control-i>", self.load_it)
    root.bind("<Control-I>", self.load_it)
    root.bind("<Control-z>", self.undo)
    root.bind("<Control-Z>", self.undo)
    root.bind("<Control-y>", self.redo)
    root.bind("<Control-Y>", self.redo)
    root.bind("<Key>", self.keyPress)

    self.set_theme_default()
    root.config(menu=self.menubar)
```

Notice that all of the code works except for positioning my widgets in the right window.
[Raw Paste](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1g6TxNa9)

Comment: I don't think you have set the window for variables to belong into. When you define a variable as a widget, you have the ability to control which parent `Tk` window it belongs to i.e. change to `self.output = Text(root, etc.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't tell a widget what its parent is, the default is the root window. In many of your widgets you aren't setting the parent window. You should *always* define the parent window.

This is particularly true when defining widgets in a class that inherits from `Frame` or `Toplevel`. When you do that, the assumption is that the class is self-contained -- that everything is a child of that class. When some of the widgets become a child of the root window, your code becomes hard to grasp because you can't make any assumptions about which widgets belong to which parents.

Notice how your terminal class is a subclass of `Frame`, but you're putting the command line and output windows inside the root window (by virtue of *not* putting it anywhere else):

```
class Terminal(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.commandline = Text(wrap=None,font=txtFont,width=40,height=1)
        ...
        self.output = Text(wrap=WORD,font=txtFont,width=40,height=30)
```

Likewise:

```
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.texteditor = Text(wrap=WORD,font=txtFont,width=120,height=20)
```

Each of the above text widgets should use `self` as the parent of the `Text` widget so that the child widgets appear inside the `Frame` widgets. For example:

```
self.texteditor = text(self, wrap=WORD, ...)
```

Comment: Ah, okay! :)

I'll switch my code so that my Text is like this: `Text(wrap=WORD,font=txtFont,width=120,height=20,parent=root)`. (and the other widgets too) :)